# Grouped UITableView space over header view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I have a `UITableView` with a `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style. I also add a table header view (not section but table). The problem is that there is a space between the start of the table view and the header view.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myHeaderView;
```

Any idea how I can get rid of this? This does not happen if I use a `UITableViewStylePlain` style

[image]

Comment: did you set frame for header view? better option is design header View in storyboard itself.

Comment: ah that was the problem. I was setting the frame of the ```myHeaderView``` after setting it as the table's header view. If I set the frame first, the assign it to the header view, it works

Comment: I added the answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are set headerView frame in viewController.

Design tableView headerView in storyboard itself.
or If you are not using storyboard/XIB change the header height.

Hop it will solve your problem .

Comment: I don't use StoryBoards

Comment: I'm using autolayout for the header view height but the frame has to be set to e.g. CGRectZero in loadView

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in the viewDidLoad of the class

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line -- 
       self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

Answer (score 0):

Override the following delegate method of UITableView to disabled the default margin.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return 0.01; // Removed the section header margin. (couldn't be 0 here, weird)
}
```